# Elasticsearch Terms on _field_names

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run a terms query on `_field_data` in elasticsearch 6.8 but I am getting an unexpected error that doesn't mean much to me.

```
GET abc/efg/_search?size=0
{
   "aggs": {
      "x": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "_field_names"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Results in:

```
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Fielddata is not supported on field [_field_names] of type [_field_names]"
      }
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

From elasticsearch 5.x, you cannot perform aggregation on the `_field_names` metadata field. This because, from 5.x onwards this field, is only indexed and it does not have `fielddata` or `doc_values` enabled.

Refer to this [Github PR](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22576) to know more about this change

Comment: @micah did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :-)

Comment: @micah can you please accept and upvote the answer, if it helped you resolve your issue :-)